# Locating qiskit

Tags: qiskit

I have read from the IBM website of 'Setting Up Your Environment' that :

> Setting up default drawer to MatPlotLib
> The default backend for `QuantumCircuit.draw()` or `qiskit.visualization.circuit_drawer()` is the text backend. However, depending on your local environment you may want to change these defaults to something better suited for your use case. This is done with the user config file. By default the user config file should be located in `~/.qiskit/` and is the `settings.conf` file.
> Qiskit Textbook uses the default circuit drawer as MatPlotLib. To reproduce visualizations as given in qiskit textbook create `settings.conf` file (usually found in `~/.qiskit/`) with contents:
> `[default] circuit_drawer = mpl`

I am new here and  do you know how to locate  `~/.qiskit/` in my system?

Comment: How about first telling what your system actually is? `~/.qiskit/ ` is the directory where you need to go if you are on Unix-like system.

Comment: My system is Mac . But I am unable to locate qiskit. Is there a way to go to the designated folder and file via Go

Comment: I hope you realize that your question is not even related to qiskit or quantum but how to use mac. See this https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-access-your-macs-hidden-files

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about quantum computing but a problem with Qiskit installation.